# the WIndows hosts file

Tags: windows-7, hosts-file

Can I map a domain to another domain (mirror)?

I wish to map `php.net` to `de.php.net`, so when I access something like `php.net/whatever`, the browser will display stuff from `de.php.net/whatever` (the mirror is faster :P).

Adding this line in the hosts file doesn't seem work:

`php.net     de.php.net`

...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it doesn't work. The hosts file maps ip addresses to host names. It does not map host names to host names or aliases to host names.

You'll need to use DNS to accomplish your goal.